Bug in polars 0.20 but not in 0.19 - any way to get around it?
I found there seems to be a bug in the latest polars versions (0.20.19) that wasn't present in 0.19. With code like:
df.group_by("SomeDate")
.agg(
        pl.col(col)
        .filter(
            pl.col(col).is_between(
                pl.quantile(col, 0.005), pl.quantile(col, 0.995)
            )
        )
        .mean()
)

This gives an error like assertion failed: lhs.len() == rhs.len() in the group_by.agg step. The same thing happens if I use min/max instead of quantiles to filter. If I used fixed values without referencing the column, it works.
One way would be do get the quantiles from the groupby, then join with the original df and finally filter each group with the quantiles. However this is going to be nasty with the current code I have since it loops over a lot of columns and also does this with many different variations. Is there some easy solution, or just stay with the older polars version until this gets fixed?

It seems to be .is_between raising. 2 comparisons should work? (x >= y) & (x <= z) or what have you. Are you able to file a minimal reproduction as a bug on the issues tracker?

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15602

Thanks for the helpful info. For now I'll downgrade and wait for the fix since it's brought up as an issue on GH. Looks like we could probably use the & statement as you said, but since I would need to make a lot of changes for that I'll ignore for now.

0.20.20 has been released with the fix included.

Nice! That was fast.
